# combining two map commands

Tags: macro

I'm doing a lot of repetitive copying.    Starting out with lines like

```
first line
second line
```

I want create a single mapping that produces

```
first line
second line
\notes{
first line
second line
}
```

I can do this with two separate macros:

```
map  ;aN 'bA^M\notes{^M}<ESC>
map  ;cp :'a,'bco'b+1<CR>
```

But when I combine them in what seems like the correct way, i.e.,

```
map  ;both 'bA^M\notes{^M}<ESC> <bar> :'a,'bco'b+1<CR>
```

The result is the as when I type `;aN` i.e., the second part of the mapping isn't implemented.    Could somebody explain please what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You do not use `<bar>` to combine mappings. You simply combine them:

```
map  ;both 'bA^M\notes{^M}<ESC>:'a,'bco'b+1<CR>
```

Some thoughts:

- As a general rule you should use `noremap` variants for you mappings.
- It is best to supply a mode. e.g. `nnoremap` for normal mode.
- Use keycode notation for readability. `^M` would become `<cr>`
- These feel like tex only mappings so maybe use a buffer local mapping. See `:h :map-local`

Next I think it would be good to look into text/latex plugins which may provide some helpful mappings. Or at the very least use something like [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) to make surrounding easier.

I would probably use a visual mode mapping like this:

```
xnoremap Sn :copy '><cr>']o}<esc>'>o\notes{<esc>^
```

Comment: Thanks!    I'll work on your suggestions, but for now, your `;both` works great.